How to fix a kitchen sink sprayer that is stuck in the ON position?
The squeeze handle on the kitchen sink sprayer somehow got stuck in the ON position and it won't turn off. If the sink faucet is turned on, it starts spraying. I can't get any of the pieces to budge and I don't understand how the mechanism works. How would I go about taking it apart?  This model sprayer is not readily available separately from the faucet, or so I've been told, and the replacements at the big box store have a base with a smaller diameter.


can you provide the brand of faucet and if possible model?

It is a Delta but I don't recall the name of the model.  I have an email in to Delta but the retailer told me they cannot get the part. Maybe Delta will say otherwise.

is the retailer blue or orange or someone else

I bought it online over 10 years ago but can't remember which etailer. I went to blue box looking for replacement parts. In the meantime, I figured out that the metal thing to the left of the circular assembly is a horse-shoe retaining clip. Pulled it out, and the entire assembly pops out.  There's a little spring about 1/2" long with about 3/16 diameter that was bent and not retracting properly into a plastic shaft, and so the prong at the center of the circular assembly wasn't being pushed back up to close off the flow. If they sell that assembly or even just the spring I should be good.

Be aware that faucets with hose and sprayer that are separate from a regular spout have a diverter valve in the faucet body that shunts water from the spout to the sprayer when the sprayer activation lever/button is pressed. This is to prevent the hose/sprayer unit from always sitting at mains pressure. If yours is this type, failure of the diverter valve in the faucet can cause your symptom...

Delta has a part page for common issues. In the comments you mention a spring and one of the part/kits includes springs, though I'm not 100% sure this will fit. While this probably isn't your faucet, it also shows that if you can identify the model each page has a part list that should allow you to purchase parts (in this example I might go with the Metal Lever Handle Kit, but as there is no picture I'm not 100% confident here either)

Thanks. I hope they get back to me since I didn't see my particular sprayer problem mentioned anywhere.
